# How do I execute a code only once all the queries inside a loop are done? (mongoose, express)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

here is my router:

```
router.get('/questions/best', function(req,res,next){
  Question.aggregate([
    // Protect against missing fields with $ifNull                                                         
    // Protect against division by zero dislikes using max[1,size]                                         
    {$project: {ratio: {$divide:[
    {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},
        {$max:[1, {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]}]}
        ]}
    }},
    {$sort: {ratio:-1}},
    {$limit: 15}
  ]).exec(function(err,results){
    if(err) {return next(err)}
    top15 = []
    for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
      Question.findOne({_id: results[i]._id}).exec(function(err,result){
        if(err){return next(err)}
        top15.push(result);
      })
    }
    res.render('content', { whichOne: 5, user: req.user, questions: top15 });
  });
});
```

don't worry about the filtering stuff, it works good, the only problem is that the template at the end of the router get rendered automatically right after the queries start, not allowing them time to push the results into an array that gets rendered into the template.
I tried using set Timeout function, but the processing time changes drastically and it is impossible to find an exact time. I think I need to use async functions? but promises do not work for some reason?

can anybody make sure the template get rendered only after all the queries return and put their values in the array?
Thanks!

Comment: `but promises do not work for some reason?` you're not using promises in the code you posted - you probably trying to use promises incorrectly, since promises makes this task trivial

Comment: Yeah I am, and the documentation does not give any good explanations for this type of thing, that is why I am here.

Comment: Why are you running an `aggregate` method on the `Question` collection and then again querying the same collection using `find` method in a for-loop? You can perform the two actions on the collection with a single `aggregate` method.

Answer (score 0):

From reading [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), using promises makes this trivial

using Promises

```
router.get('/questions/best', (req,res,next) => {
    Question.aggregate([
        // Protect against missing fields with $ifNull                                                         
        // Protect against division by zero dislikes using max[1,size]                                         
        {$project: {ratio: {$divide:[
        {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},
            {$max:[1, {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]}]}
            ]}
        }},
        {$sort: {ratio:-1}},
        {$limit: 15}
    ]).exec()
    .then(results => Promise.all(results.map(({_id}) => Question.findOne({_id}).exec())))
    .then(questions => res.render('content', { whichOne: 5, user: req.user, questions}))
    .catch(next);
});
```

or, using async/await

```
router.get('/questions/best', async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const results = await Question.aggregate([
            // Protect against missing fields with $ifNull                                                         
            // Protect against division by zero dislikes using max[1,size]                                         
            {$project: {ratio: {$divide:[
            {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$likes",[0]]}, 0]},
                {$max:[1, {$arrayElemAt:[{$ifNull:["$dislikes",[0]]}, 0]}]}
                ]}
            }},
            {$sort: {ratio:-1}},
            {$limit: 15}
        ]).exec();
        const questions = await Promise.all(results.map(({_id}) => Question.findOne({_id}).exec()));
        res.render('content', { whichOne: 5, user: req.user, questions});
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```